# Is it possible to retrieve schema from avro data and use them in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro

I've used avro-tools to convert my avro schema into Java class, which I pass it into `Avro-Map-Input-Key-Schema` for data processing. This is all working fine.

But recently I had to add a new column to avro schema and recompile the java class.

This is where I encountered a problem as my previously generated data were serialized by the old scheme, so my MapReduce jobs is now failing after modifying the schema, even though my MapReduce logic isn't using the new column.

Therefore, I was wondering whether I could stop passing in the Java schema class and retrieve the schema from the data and process the data (dynamically), is this possible.

I assume it isn't!

Answer (score 0):

Yea, there's not.  But you can read it as a `GenericRecord` and then map the fields to your updated type object.  I go through this at a high level [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979282/reading-avro-format-data-in-hadoop-map-reduce/30196742#30196742).

Comment: We're going to help the community with problems like these soon: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AVRO-1699

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to read existing data with an updated schema. Avro will always read a file using the schema from its header, but if you also supply an expected schema (or "read schema") then Avro will create records that conform to that requested schema. That ends up skipping fields that aren't requested or filling in defaults for fields that are missing from the file.

In this case, you want to set the read schema and data model for your MapReduce job like this:

```
AvroJob.setInputSchema(job, MyRecord.getClassSchema());
AvroJob.setDataModelClass(job, SpecificData.class);
```